# R-markdown table entering manually the content

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on an r-markdown document and would like to insert a table that explains common logical and boolean operators(thus have nothing to do with my data frame). I think I will have to enter it by hand but do not know the latex writing I need to use. I do knit my document as a pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats how you create a 'manual' table in r-markdown (no need for latex code if you don't want to use it ;):

```
## Manual table

Table Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
  Table Cell  | Cell 2
Cell 3        | Cell 4
```